# Problem Requesting Notification Permissions in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I am trying to request the Notification Permission in a Composable.

I've been following online examples, and I can't get it to work. However, the same code, when requesting the Camera permission instead, works as expected, and I don't know why. And yes, the permission is in my manifest, and the notifications do work.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun Foo() {
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted ->
        if (isGranted) {
            println("permission granted")
        } else {
            println("permission not granted")
        }
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    NotificationButton(
        onClick = {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 // permission granted
            } else {
                launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: When you say you can't get it to work, what's happening when you run and press the button?

I just tried out the code you posted and it displayed the runtime permission request when I pressed the button (and displayed "permission granted" in logcat.

What's your minSdk, compileSdk and targetSdk?

Comment: When I press the button, nothing happens. I don't get the permission request, and logcat let's me know that the permission is not granted, meaning it should have sent the request. When I change it to the camera permission, it works fine. My min sdk is 26, target sdk is 33, and compile sdk is also 33.

Comment: I should have asked - what SDK version is your emulator? If it's < 33, you won't see a dialog as the permission didn't exist. That would be one cause. Another - try uninstalling and reinstalling the app. If you had denied permission on an earlier run, that sticks and after two denies, the system will ignore permission requests. If you allowed on a previous run, that'll stick. Based on seeing "permission granted", I get the feeling you might have allowed on an earlier run. Uninstalling will clear it to try again (or you can explicitly clear it from the app info)

Comment: On SDK < 33 you probably wouldn't see "permission granted" as the self check should just return granted. So feels more like the permission may be there from a previous run.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed to admit, but all it took was uninstalling and reinstalling the app. I had tested the permission earlier outside of the composable and kept rejecting it so it would continue to pop up. Also, I was using my phone as a test device, so SDK version was not an issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries - happens to me all the time! I'll work my comments into an answer for this so it can help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP clarified that they saw "permission granted" when clicking the button.

This meant that the permission launcher was being called and returning "granted".

The POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission was introduced in SDK 33 (Tiramisu).

If the application were run in SDK < 33 (on an emulator or physical device), the SDK doesn't know about the permission, and the checkSelfPermission call would just return "granted".

When running with SDK >= 33, the only way to get to that "permission granted" path is if the launcher were run and returned granted status.

You can verify this by looking at the app info (**Settings > Apps > Your App > Permissions**) and see if the Notifications permission has been allowed.

You can either uncheck that permission or uninstall the application. (When developing and testing permissions, I usually find it faster to uninstall and re-run. (You can also revoke permissions via adb).

Comment: The function says that it requires Tiramisu which means it would throw an error if this function is called when the device build is less than Tiramisu, hence further debugging and the full context of the problem is required for a solution to be proposed.

Comment: The requiresApi is a lint error but doesn't block the build (assuming compileSdk 34; I tested that, running on SDK 32, 33 and 34). The function also works without that annotation.